# how to sync production database schemas to DEV and QC in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

we now have a hundred of instances(each instance has about 10+ databases) in production environment. and also have DEV and QC environment.

how we could make DEV and QC environment synced with Production periodly?

```
 anyone has a good solution for it?
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at Redgate's SQL‌ compare. 
https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index

Comment: Alternatively, [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). The need to sync schema from physical production databases suggests an issue with the SDLC, though.